# How can I apply the DRY principle to commenting?

Tags: javascript, standards, dry

I have multiple functions using the same complex line of code that I needed to comment.

```
function thisFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  // Comment for clarification
  *complex code line*
}

function thatFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  // Comment for clarification
  *complex code line*
}

function anotherFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  // Comment for clarification
  *complex code line*
}
```

The main issue I see was having to explain for different functions the same complex code multiple times with the **exact same comment**.

This goes against the DRY principle. My question is, "What would be the best practice to resolve this problem and still let readers understand my code?"

My overall thought was to only comment the first usage for that complex line. However, I don't know if this would be 100% intuitive for other people if they are reading.

EDIT: For clarification, I have one line of code used in multiple functions. I don't know if I should keep the duplicated comments, comment only the first usage of the complex line, or create a helper function that each of the current functions can use even if that helper function only contains the comment and the one complex code line. Ideas?

Comment: It's difficult to give a specific answer without any context because the obvious remark would be to move code to an external function. I suppose you're asking because you're using the same logic in code that's physically different but...

Comment: ^^ What @ÁlvaroGonzález said. In fact, I posted it as an answer initially, but he's right, we really need more info.

Comment: The functions each have unique code which I marked as "[Some code..]" The only thing they share in common is the complex line of code which needs a comment. We could make a helper function that only executes that one line of code and inside the function there will be a comment. I don't believe that creating a helper function for 1 line of code is a good idea.

Comment: I disagree. A helper function for one complex line of code that is repeatedly called is a great idea. If that line of code needed to change, do you want to make that same edit throughout your code base? I have many helper functions of 1-3 lines of code, often some of the most widely used and helpful of all.

Comment: Also, as someone who has spent years working on a code base that hundreds of people have had their hands in, if you asked me how often I've come across a helper function that wasn't really useful, the answer is less than once per year. If you asked me how often I find code that would be more readable or maintainable if it were to have used more helper functions, the answer is almost daily. If you had to err on one side, err on more helper functions, not fewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encapsulate the complex code into it's own function, and provide the comments once:

```
function thisFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  complexCodeFunction();
}

function thatFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  complexCodeFunction();
}

function anotherFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  complexCodeFunction();  
}

//comment for clarification
function complexCodeFunction(){
    *complex code*
}
```

Comment: This is why people should go through an OOP language before taking up fullstack javascript -- and yes, before the javascript huggers attack me, I'm well aware javascript is 'considered' an OOP language. You know what I mean.

Comment: @Ted would it be wrong to make the common function only account for one line. This complex code is a single line which would only perform that logic.

Comment: @M.Slomski Someone famous in C.S. land said that code should be written so humans can read and understand it.  Your priority should be to make it intelligible for your coworkers, and for yourself, in case you need to refactor it 18 months from now...

Comment: @M.Slomski Wrapping complex logic in a function also facilitates testing...

Comment: @M.Slomski It is perfectly acceptable, and often desirable, to encapsulate single-line complex functionality into a single, descriptively-named method. That helps with upstream readability, and even makes the code somewhat self-documenting, since the new method's name describes what the complex functionality is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In case all the lines of complex code are exactly the same, it should be possible to extract them out into a separate function:

```
function thisFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  complexOperation();
}

function thatFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  // Comment for clarification
  complexOperation();
}

function anotherFunction() {
  [Some Code..]
  complexOperation();
}

function complexOperation() {
   //comment for clarification
   *complex code line*
}
```

In case the complex line of code is not easily extractible or the lines differ in some key aspects, I don't think it is a problem to duplicate the comments. The DRY principle applies mainly to code itself, comments are a clarification for the developer, so that the code is more understandable. If the comments help the reader to understand the code better, there is no reason to avoid this duplication.

Comment: Yes it would :-) . And you can even give the newly added function a descriptive name that will further improve readability and understandability of the code.